# Formula that enumerates selections of combinations?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I was wondering if there was a formula which enumerates all possible combinations for $n$ sets, with $s$ sets being selected from $k$ intersection sets.
For example $n=5$,$s=3$,$k=3$ would give sets $\{ 1,2,3,4,5 \}$ of which $k=3$ have intersections between each other,
$\{ 123,124,125,134,135,145,234,235,245,345 \}$ for total of $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{5}{3}=10$ combinations, of which $s=3$ are selected to be enumerated for all possible combinations.

There are 8 combinations of type $123,124,x$ where $x$ is one of the sets not equal to $123,124$.
There are 7 combinations of type $123,125,x$ where $x$ is one of the sets not equal to $123,125$ and not equal to $124$... Continuing this way gives the summation of $$\sum_{i=1}^{8} i(8-i+1)=\sum_{i=1}^{8}\sum_{j=1}^{8-i+1} i =120$$

I am not sure how 8 is obtained, but i'm assuming it is some function of $n,s,k$? In some cases i got it to be $u=\binom{n}{k}-s+1$, but how do you determine the full equation?
Another example would be for $n=5,s=4,k=3$ gives

$$\sum_{i=1}^{7} \sum_{j=1}^{8-i} ij =210 $$

In general it looks to be something like

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{u} i \sum_{j=1}^{u-i+1} j$$

but i'm not sure what it looks like for many cases

Comment: Hint... $\binom{10}{3} = 120$ and $\binom{10}{4}=210$.  Additionally, $\binom{5}{3}=10$

Comment: Ok i see you are saying this is equal to $\binom{\binom{n}{k}}{s}$ but how do you derive this?

Comment: Nevermind, i see what you mean, there are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to choose an unordered subset of $k$ sets from $n$ sets, and that follows choosing an unordered subset of $s$ sets from $\binom{n}{k}$ sets. I was thinking that maybe this has a special generating function, but this explains it. Thanks